# Display:none; display: block to show/hide div in table

Tags: html, css

As the title states, I am facing some issues with my webpage. I can't seem to be able to show/ hide a div through css3 and cannot figure out what I have done wrong.. I have used this method before, and it has worked flawlessly...

Is the table causing the issues? Here is my HTML and CSS

```
<html>
<head>
<title>AMCON_website_home3</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
.hidden {

display:none;

}
#cambriapopup {

background-image:cambria-popup-background.gif;
width:125;
height:201;
z-index:10;
}

.show:hover + .hidden { 
display:block;

}

</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (AMCON_website_home3.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="961" height="667" border="0" cellpadding="0"             cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="15">
        <img src="images/backgournd.gif" width="960" height="442" alt="">       </td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="442" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="9" rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/backgournd-03.gif" width="656" height="203"     alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="5">
        <div id="cambriapopup" class="hidden">WTF</div></td>
    <td rowspan="9">
        <img src="images/backgournd-05.gif" width="179" height="225"    alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="201" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="8">
        <img src="images/cambria-popup-background-06.gif" width="9"     height="24" alt=""></td>
    <div id="show" class="show"><td rowspan="8">
        <img src="images/AMCON_website_home3_06.gif" width="24" height="24"     id="show" alt=""></td></div>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/cambria-popup-background-08.gif" width="92"     height="3" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <img src="images/backgournd-09.gif" width="57" height="1" alt="">      </td>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/AMCON_website_home3_09.gif" width="20" height="18" alt=""></td>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/backgournd-11.gif" width="579" height="3" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="images/backgournd-12.gif" width="39" height="1" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/AMCON_website_home3_12.gif" width="17" height="17" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="6">
        <img src="images/backgournd-14.gif" width="1" height="21" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="6">
        <img src="images/cambria-popup-background-15.gif" width="5" height="21" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <div class="show"><img src="images/AMCON_website_home3_15.gif" width="78" height="19" id="show" alt=""></div></td>
    <td rowspan="6">
        <img src="images/cambria-popup-background-17.gif" width="9" height="21" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/backgournd-18.gif" width="21" height="20" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/AMCON_website_home3_18.gif" width="15" height="15" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <img src="images/backgournd-20.gif" width="3" height="20" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/backgournd-21.gif" width="3" height="19" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/AMCON_website_home3_21.gif" width="46" height="14" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="4">
        <img src="images/backgournd-23.gif" width="530" height="19" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="14" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/backgournd-24.gif" width="15" height="5" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="images/backgournd-25.gif" width="46" height="5" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/backgournd-26.gif" width="17" height="4" alt=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/backgournd-27.gif" width="20" height="4" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="images/cambria-popup-background-28.gif" width="78"     height="2" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <img src="images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors/bad habits in your code unrelated to the hiding/displaying of a div on hover such as giving elements style attributes like `margin="10px"` you should give the element a id or class (if the styles are used more than once) and style it in a stylesheet

> But this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44WZP/2/) should be what you are
>   looking for to show/hide a div.
>
> ```
> .hidden {
>     display:none;
>     height:200px;
>     width:200px;
>     background-color:#000;
> }
> .show:hover+.hidden, .hidden:hover {
>     display:block;
> }
> ```

---

### EDIT

To achieve what you are looking for you will need to use javascript/jQuery because of the way you have set out your table. this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uSDP/) shows you how to do this with jQuery. Include this in the head tag of your html.

```
<script>
    $(".show").on("mouseover", function () {
        $(".hidden").show();
    });
    $(".show").on("mouseout", function () {
        $(".hidden").hide();
    }); 
</script>
```

you will Also need to link to the jQuery library in you head tags, so before the code above add

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help with "giving elements style attributes"

That will save me tremendous amounts of time in the near future.

I have tried your show/hide code, and have not achieved any positive results :(

Comment: No problem and because of the way you have your table set out you will need to use some JavaScript/jQuery to get the effect you are looking for, I shall update my op to show you how.